# Limit of $\sum\frac{1}{p(\pi(n))}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p(n)$ be the nth prime and $\pi(n)$ the number of primes not exceeding n.

I wonder if we can show that

$$\tag{1} S = \sum_{n= 2}^k \frac{1}{ p (\pi (n))} \sim \log k. $$

We know by comparison with $T= \sum \frac{1}{p(n)}$ that S diverges and is larger than T.

Also we can re-write S as $$S = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{g(n)}{p(n)} $$

in which $g(n)$ is the prime gap $g(n) = p(n+1)-p(n).$ This led me to doubt we can prove (1). Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Your first equation is meant to be read as $\sim \log k$ as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: Yeah, that is *really* bad terminology. You can write $S_k\sim \log k$, but don't put the limit. The limit is $+\infty$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $p(\pi(n))$ is the largest prime $\le n$. By the Prime Number Theorem for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $N_\epsilon$ such that
$$
n(1-\epsilon) < p(\pi(n)) \le n
$$
for all $n>N_\epsilon$.
So for $k>N_{\epsilon}$
$$
S_k = \sum_{n=2}^k \frac{1}{p(\pi(k))} = S_{N_\epsilon}+\sum_{n=N_\epsilon+1}^k\frac{1}{p(\pi(k))}\\
H_k-H_{N_\epsilon}\le S_k-S_{N_\epsilon}<\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}(H_k-H_{N_\epsilon})
$$
where $H_k=\sum_{n=1}^k n^{-1}$ is the harmonic number.

So
$$
1 \le \frac{S_k-C_\epsilon}{H_k-D_\epsilon} < \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}
$$
where $C_\epsilon,D_\epsilon$ are constants depending on $\epsilon$, and $S_k,H_k$ are unbounded as $k\to \infty$, so
$$
S_k \sim H_k \sim \log k
$$